# Why does rm *(1)* remove all files in a directory?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I expected that:

```
$ rm *(1)*
```

would remove all files containing `(1)` in the name. I was wrong. It removed all files in the directory.

Why?

Comment: Whenever I use `rm` with a pattern, I always precede it by `echo` before issuing the actual command.  The habit saved me more than once (ever since, as a 6 year old or so, confusing the difference between `DEL A: *.*` and `DEL *.* A:`).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
*(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
```

You have a glob expression which matches files beginning with zero or more `1`s - which is all files.

One simple way to disable this globbing behaviour is to `\` escape the parentheses:

```
rm *\(1\)*
```

Otherwise you can use `shopt -u extglob` to disable the behaviour and `shopt -s extglob` to re-enable it:

```
shopt -u extglob
rm *(1)*
shopt -s extglob
```

Note that as [Stephane says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120206/why-does-rm-1-remove-all-files-in-a-directory/120207#comment189149_120207), `extglob` is enabled by `bash-completion` so disabling it may cause completion functions not to work properly.

Comment: Note that `extglob` is not on by default but is turned on by bash_completion if you have that installed and enabled. `bash` doesn't have local scope for options like `zsh` does.

Comment: Also note that `bash-4.3` has a regression in that `*(1)*` also expands hidden files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Do you have a link for the bug relating to that regression? Thanks

Comment: @Basic, [here you go](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/21266). Chet hasn't replied yet.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably related to the `extglob` shell option. If I turn it off, the pattern produces an error message:

```
martin@dogmeat:~$ shopt -u extglob
martin@dogmeat:~$ shopt extglob
extglob         off
martin@dogmeat:~$ echo *(1)*
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If I turn it on, it indeed seems to match everything. The manpage documents these patterns, I think they are related:

```
   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
   extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
   description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
   by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol‐
   lowing sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

I don't see any documentation that specifies what parenthesis without a leading character do. Anyway, you can circumvent the issue by quoting the parens:

```
martin@dogmeat ~ % echo *\(1\)*
A(1)b
```

Also, use `echo` or `ls` to test your pattern first if you aren't absolutely sure that's working :)

Comment: FYI: `{` is a brace, `(` is a paren (or round bracket).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm not a native English speaker so I tend to confuse them :)

Comment: In British: `{` = curly bracket, `(` = round bracket, `[` = square bracket.  In American: `{` = brace, `(` = paren, `[` = bracket.  A bit confusing.  If you ever need to check what something's called, [Jargon File - ASCII](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html) is quite helpful.

Comment: @Mikel Thanks, I also checked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) so now I know about _flower brackets_ and the _squirrelly_ ones!

Comment: In Indian English, `{` is a flower bracket, `[` is a square bracket, and `(` is a round bracket or more commonly just bracket. :-)